# React useEffect dependency not triggering from async callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I've tried to break this down to it's simplest components to understand why the `useEffect` in `ButtonStatus` is not updating when the state of `eventDataId` is updated in the `processClickButton` function of the `ButtonView` React Component.  In this example, I'm making calls to ethereum's smart contract on my local Ganache instance, and that is working fine and returning a vew eventDataId with each call.

The use case: a user clicks a button, `handleButtonClick` fires off a request (in this case an ethereum smart contract call), and in the `on()` function, we set the state of `eventDataId`.  I *hoped* this would then trigger the `ButtonStatus` `useEffect` by way of it's dependencies array, specifically `[eventDataId]`.  I think this in turn should look up additional info and render the `MintStatus`.

```
// I've removed all extraneous lines of code, for example the .catch() and .error() handlers on the contract.methods calls.

import React, { useEffect, useState} from 'react';
const Web3 = require('web3');

const ButtonStatus = ({contract, account}) => {

    const [eventDataId, setEventDataId] = useState();
    const [additionalData, setAdditionalData] = useState();

    function retrieveAdditionalData(contract, account) {
        contract.methods.additionalData()
        .call({ from: account })
        .then(function(res) {
            setAdditionalData(res);
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        retrieveAdditionalData(contract, account);
    }, [eventDataId]);

    return (
        <div>Event Data Id is {eventDataId} with {additionalData}</div>
    );
}

class ButtonView extends React.Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            eventDataId: undefined
        };
        this.handleButtonClick = this.handleButtonClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleButtonClick() {
        const setState = this.setState.bind(this);   
        const contract = this.props.contract;
        const account = this.props.account;

        contract.methods.doSomething()
        .send({ from: account })
        .on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){
            let eventDataId = receipt.events['Data Event'].returnValues.eventDataId;
            setState({ eventDataId: eventDataId });
        });      
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>Click Me</button>
            <ButtonStatus contract={this.props.contract} account={this.props.account} />
        );
    }
}

export default ButtonView;
```

I'm sure I'm missing some fundamental concept here.  Does the behind-the-scenes "workings" of `React{ useState }` even associate the `eventDataId` `state` value from `ButtonView` to the `state` value in `ButtonStatus`.  I suspect this is the where the trouble lies.

In short, I'm looking for help understanding how the response from `contract.methods.doSomething().on(...)` can trigger the `useEffect` of `ButtonStatus`.

Comment: You're never calling `setEventDataId`, so the effect that depends only on `eventDataId` won't run (except on mount)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Can I call `setEventDataId` from within `ButtonView` or it's `handleButtonClick()` method?  I'm confused about how those are brought together.

Comment: Yes, if you move the state to the parent. https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are wanting the `useEffect` hook in `ButtonStatus` to run when the `eventDataId` state in the parent `ButtonView` updates. When the state in the parent updates it will trigger a rerender, and thus rerender the child `ButtonStatus` component. You can pass `this.state.eventDataId` in as a prop to be used in the `useEffect`'s dependency array.

ButtonView

```
render() {
  return (
    <button onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>Click Me</button>
    <ButtonStatus
      contract={this.props.contract}
      account={this.props.account}
      eventDataId={this.state.eventDataId}
    />
  );
}
```

ButtonStatus

```
const ButtonStatus = ({ account, contract, eventDataId }) => {
  const [additionalData, setAdditionalData] = useState();

  function retrieveAdditionalData(contract, account) {
    contract.methods.additionalData()
      .call({ from: account })
      .then(function(res) {
        setAdditionalData(res);
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    retrieveAdditionalData(contract, account);
  }, [eventDataId]);

  return (
    <div>Event Data Id is {eventDataId} with {additionalData}</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This along with the link from @CertainPerformance (https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) did the trick.  In the end, I added the `eventDataId` to the state of `ButtonViews` parent, since it affected multiple child Components.